# How to countif or sumif in google sheet with background color count based on other cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I have google sheet, I'm able to count same background colored column in the sheet with help of this addon  "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb"

Now I want to add condition here, I just want to count background color only if B column empty. How can I do that?

This is what now I have

[image]

And this is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to count background color only if B column empty

you can wrap it into `IF` fx:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:B)=0, COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("A2:A9", "A2", A2:A9), "pending")
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but it only shows values if Column b empty, if column B has any value its shows just blank cell as like above in your 2nd image, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Sorry, I thing its misunderstanding my question means count colors from column A only that one's in which column B empty. not means that all column B empty. like above in my image i post in question 2nd image 3 colors count as they are empty value in column B . hope you understand now .

Comment: I mean dont count cell from Column A if front of cell in column B have "Done" Value

Comment: Thanks For help I just remove A2:A9 from last and its work as I need "=COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("A2:A","A2") - COUNTIF(B2:B,"Done") " Thanks Again

Comment: sorry again, it's not working as I need when I applied it on my original datasheet. I have data of pending invoices so I use conditional format for duplicate invoice entries. Now we can count duplicate entries with bg color. when we paid invoice we mark with "Done" in the next B column I just want this formula to count only duplicate entries which are still pending. We left Column B empty and only enter the value "Done" when we paid the invoice. so the above method count all previous data also so I got the wrong number with this formula. Hope you got my point. Thanks from Heart for your help.

Comment: for the hint I count total invoice by using this formula "="Pending " & SUMIF(H:H,"",F:F) "  So its count only F column if H column empty , so if we mark h with done its not count that value in f hope you understand now . sorry for bad English. And sorry it's my mistake I don't describe my problem, and yes  you provide good answer as per understanding

Answer (score 1):

Paste this script in the script-editor and save it.

```
function countBackGroudIf(range, reference, colorColumn, conditionColumn, condition) {
  var sheet, color, colors, values;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  color = sheet.getRange(reference).getBackground();
  colors = sheet.getRange(range).getBackgrounds().map(function (v) {
    return v[colorColumn-1]
  });
  values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues().map(function (v) {
    return v[conditionColumn-1]
  });
  return values.filter(function (el, ind) {
      return el === condition && colors[ind] === color;
  }).length
}
```

Then in your spreadsheet try this formula

```
=countBackGroudIf("A2:B20", "A3", 1, 2,)
```

See if that works?